# How to I keep spark Label from wrapping in the middle of a word?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I have a spark label with a fixed width, like so:

```
<s:Label text="the quick brown fox jumped over thelazydogsPackmyboxwithfive dozen liquor jugs." width="400"/>
```

The big cluster of words (thelazydogsPackmyboxwithfive) extends beyond the width, and so the line breaks after the word "over".  This is the desired behavior.

BUT, when I use an embedded font, this no longer happens.  The line breaks in between the "o" and "x" of "thelazydogsPackmyboxwithfive".  How can I keep breaks from occurring in the middle of words and still use my embedded font?

Comment: Does it happen with _any_ embedded font, or just the one? In the last case the font is probably at fault.

Comment: Ah, good call.  Embedding a different font fixes the issue.  If you want to resubmit this comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine with me and does the word break correct, as in it moves the `thelazydogsPackmyboxwithfive` down one line when it can't fit it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        @font-face{
            src:url("Knights Quest.ttf");
            fontFamily: MyF;
            embedAsCFF: true;
        }
        .myFont
        {
            fontFamily: MyF;
            fontSize:20px;
        }

    </fx:Style>


    <s:BorderContainer id="box" width="400" height="200">

    </s:BorderContainer>

    <s:Label text="the quick brown fox jumped over thelazydogsPackmyboxwithfive dozen liquor jugs." width="400" styleName="myFont" />

</s:Application>
```

Here is how it looks :

[image]